# Possibility to adjust brightness or to apply blur effect on Leaflet Map?

Tags: google-maps, css, leaflet

I know it is possible with Google Map API v3 (`MapTypeStyler` option) but do you think it is with Leaflet API ?

Thing is that I have text that cover a map I need to make more visible by adjusting brightness or - even better - by applying blur effect like in this example : http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-filter/

CSS shader looks very promising [but supported only with latest Chrome browser](http://iweb.uz/azik/interactive-globe-with-css-shaders-and-google-maps/).

The text over the map is modal (user must interact with button) and I could add overlay with a PNG image file. I don't like to much this solution that need unnecessary file to be transfered to the client.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaflet is very lightweight and simply puts references to tile images on your html page. So I see two options to change the look of the tiles:

**CSS**

Which indeed depends on the browser.

**Custom tiles**

Leaflet will display tiles from any server. You can for example pick [one of the many styles served by cloudmade](http://maps.cloudmade.com/editor) or make one of your own there.
Or use a tool like [TileMill](http://mapbox.com/tilemill/) to create (and perhaps even host) them yourself.

Comment: Hi flup, thank for the reply. I understand Leaflet "Fresh" tile is served by cloudmade. Do you know if there is limitation using the API, as for Google Map v3 ? TileMill looks great but probably I will fallback to Bing or Google Map sattelite styles that actually Leaflet supports.

Comment: I'm not too good at reading legalese. What I understand of CloudMade Terms and Conditions is that you must attribute the data and share derived works. There's a maximum usage I suspect. You can host your own TileMill tiles using MBTiles server or on the MapBox servers for a fee. Leaflet supports MBTiles just fine.